# How to deny access to the default domain in AWS AppRunner

Tags: amazon-web-services, infrastructure, amazon-app-runner, aws-app-runner

I have an application created in Nextjs and hosted in AppRunner. I currently have access to the default domain created by AppRunner and a custom domain tied to AppRunner. How best to set up an AWS environment to meet the following requirements?

- Access to custom domains is possible, but not to the default domain
- I have WAF in place before AppRunner, but I don't want to change the WAF settings

I thought I could set AppRunner to private access and deny access to the default domain using the VPC endpoint, but was unable to achieve this. Can someone please help me with this?